# select and delete rows within groups using mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates

I've seen examples for duplicate row manipulation, but I can't figure out how to map them to solve my problem.

```
+----+------------+------+---------+
| id | date       | file | status  |
+----+------------+------+---------+
|  1 | 2011-12-01 |    1 | Pending |
|  2 | 2011-12-02 |    1 | Pending |
|  3 | 2011-12-03 |    1 | Done    |
|  4 | 2011-12-04 |    1 | Pending |
|  5 | 2011-12-05 |    1 | Done    |
|  6 | 2011-12-06 |    1 | Pending |
|  7 | 2011-12-07 |    1 | Pending |
|  8 | 2011-12-08 |    1 | Pending |
|  9 | 2011-12-09 |    2 | Pending |
| 10 | 2011-12-10 |    2 | Pending |
| 11 | 2011-12-11 |    3 | Pending |
| 12 | 2011-12-12 |    4 | Done    |
| 13 | 2011-12-13 |    5 | Pending |
| 14 | 2011-12-14 |    5 | Done    |
| 15 | 2011-12-15 |    5 | Pending |
+----+------------+------+---------+
```

For each file in the table:

1. I need to first select/delete any row where status='Pending', and its date is older than the youngest date for any row where status='Done'.  For the example, this would select/delete rows with id 1, 2, 4, and 13.
2. I need to next select/delete any row where status='Pending' and it's not the oldest date where status='Pending'.  For the example, this would select/delete rows with id 7, 8, and 10.

The resulting table is:

```
+----+------------+------+---------+
| id | date       | file | status  |
+----+------------+------+---------+
|  3 | 2011-12-03 |    1 | Done    |
|  5 | 2011-12-05 |    1 | Done    |
|  6 | 2011-12-06 |    1 | Pending |
|  9 | 2011-12-09 |    2 | Pending |
| 11 | 2011-12-11 |    3 | Pending |
| 12 | 2011-12-12 |    4 | Done    |
| 14 | 2011-12-14 |    5 | Done    |
| 15 | 2011-12-15 |    5 | Pending |
+----+------------+------+---------+
```

---

This will create and populate the test table in MySQL:

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `file` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (1,'2011-12-01',1,'Pending '),(2,'2011-12-02',1,'Pending '),(3,'2011-12-03',1,'Done'),(4,'2011-12-04',1,'Pending '),(5,'2011-12-05',1,'Done'),(6,'2011-12-06',1,'Pending '),(7,'2011-12-07',1,'Pending '),(8,'2011-12-08',1,'Pending '),(9,'2011-12-09',2,'Pending '),(10,'2011-12-10',2,'Pending '),(11,'2011-12-11',3,'Pending '),(12,'2011-12-12',4,'Done'),(13,'2011-12-13',5,'Pending '),(14,'2011-12-14',5,'Done'),(15,'2011-12-15',5,'Pending ');

---

Thanks to ziesemer for the correct SELECT queries--I learned a lot from them.  Unfortunately, it appears that MySQL doesn't allow DELETE with a subquery, so I converted ziesemer's answer to use JOINS instead.  But I'm a SQL noob, so please correct if these could be improved:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM test t1 INNER JOIN test t2
 WHERE t1.file = t2.file
   AND t1.status = 'Pending'
   AND t2.status = 'Done'
   AND t1.date < t2.date;

SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM test t1 INNER JOIN test t2
 WHERE t1.file = t2.file
   AND t1.status = 'Pending'
   AND t2.status = 'Pending'
   AND t1.date > t2.date;
```

To delete, replace the SELECT line with:

```
DELETE t1 FROM test t1 INNER JOIN test t2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have these tested, working independently - though the 2nd must be executed after the 1st to get the results you provided in your example.  I am having some difficulty getting them to work as one Select, as the 2nd query is dependent upon the state of the table after the 1st is complete...

```
Select *
    From my_table t1
    Where (status = 'Pending'
        And date < (
            Select Max(date)
                From my_table t2
                Where t2.file = t1.file
                    And t2.status = 'Done'));

Select *
    From my_table t1
    Where (status = 'Pending'
        And date > (
            Select Min(date)
                From my_table t2
                Where t2.file = t1.file
                    And t2.status = 'Pending'));
```

(I'll give a +1 to anyone else who's answer can do this in one query, while producing the same, accurate results - I'm stumped, for now.)

Comment: It doesn't need to a single select or delete, if it's not possible.  But I'm having trouble turning these selects into deletes.  Can you show me how to do that?  I'm using 5.5.16.  Thank you.

Comment: Just replace the first `Select * From` with `Delete From` (only on the outer query, not the inner query).

Comment: That's what I had tried:

    mysql> Delete
        ->     From test t1
        ->     Where (status = 'Pending'
        ->         And date < (
        ->             Select Max(date)
        ->                 From test t2
        ->                 Where t2.file = t1.file
        ->                     And t2.status = 'Done'));
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't1
        Where (status = 'Pending'
            And date < (
                Select Max(dat' at line 2

Comment: I didn't actually test this on MySQL, but I was hoping what I wrote was portable.  If you could provide a Create Table and Insert statements to recreate your test table with data to make this easier to test with in MySQL, I'll take another look at it tomorrow.

Comment: I think the issue was with trying to do a DELETE query that contains a subquery, which MySQL doesn't allow. I've added an answer with a conversion of your correct answer to use JOINs instead.

Comment: @osoviejo - An interesting find about the conversion to DELETE problem:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2920

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem will be solved by the below query, just you need to to do a subselect:

```
delete from tables1 where (select * from table1 where status=pending AND file=1 AND date>2011-12-05)
```

for the other one it needs a little thinking. (let me think about it)